# ngx-admin / nebular how to create page outside pages module?

Tags: angular, nebular, ngx-admin

I just experimenting ngx-admin, I want to create a page that has no header and footer like pages,
so I create a module with

> ng g m print --route print --module app.module

inside routes

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'pages',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/pages.module')
      .then(m => m.PagesModule),
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'pages', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'print', loadChildren: () => import('./print/print.module').then(m => m.PrintModule) },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'pages' },
];
```

in pages-menu.ts

```
export const MENU_ITEMS: NbMenuItem[] = [
  {
    title: 'E-commerce',
    icon: 'shopping-cart-outline',
    link: '/pages/dashboard',
    home: true,
  },
  {
    title: 'Print',
    link: '/print'
  },.....// the original menu in here
```

When I run and clikc the print link, it just show blank page with nothing inside. I still have no idea how to create custom page in ngx-admin

I follow the instruction in here https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/auth/custom-auth-components#related-articles but it doesnt work as well.

I use angular 11 for this project and latest ngx-admin

Comment: You need to create new layout for that. Default layout has header and footer. You can see how it is injected under `@theme\layouts`. Check [here](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/layout/overview#nblayoutcomponent) might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create print module & component outside the page module

> ng g m print --routing=true
> ng g c print --inline-template=true --skip-tests=true --inline-style=true

2. inside print.component.ts do this

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-print',
  template: `
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
  styles: [
  ]
})
export class PrintComponent implements OnInit {   
  constructor() { }    
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }    
}
```

3. On app-routing.module.ts add:

> {
> path: 'print',
> loadChildren: () => import('./print/print.module').then( m => m.PrintModule)   },

4. Now try to access it from /print/
   it shouold load your empty page without any layout components.

Comment: in this process not showing any error but it's still loading/no rendering any page content

Answer (score 0):

You should create `PrintRoutingModule` on `Print` folder, then import that file to `PrintModule`.

`print-routing.module.ts`

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: PrintComponent,
  },
];

const config: ExtraOptions = {
  useHash: false,
  relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy'
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class PrintRoutingModule {
}
```

it works for me, or you can change the

`{ path: 'print', loadChildren: () => import('./print/print.module').then(m => m.PrintModule) },`

to

```
  {
    path: 'print',
    component: PrintComponent,
  },
```

both produce the same thing

Comment: This is not working. I have done like you do.

Comment: can u make a minimal reproduce using stackblitz?